In the US, do natives often use "I always knew" instead of "I have always known" when they refer to "time up to now"?
According to my textbook:

always, ever and never
In an informal style, a simple past tense is sometimes possible with always, ever and never when they refer to 'time up to now'.

I always knew I could trust you. (OR I've always known…)
Did you ever see anything like that before? (OR Have you ever seen…)


In the US, do natives often use "I always knew" instead of "I have always known" when they refer to "time up to now"?

Yes.  "I always knew" is very common, probably more frequent in such contexts than "I have always known".  At least in AmE.   "I always knew this day was coming."

Americans tend to use perfect mode less than Brits.

I think that particular phrase is pretty common in BrE as well.

It seems a bit weird to say "I always knew I could trust you" without adding some qualification, e.g. "I always knew I could trust you but when you did such and such that confirmed it". But certainly simple past is fine in similar circumstances.

@StuartF Sometimes the second part is implicit. After they do something, you say "Thanks, I always knew I could trust you."

linguist poo-bahs use the term "neutralized" - the "always" neutralizes the difference between "knew" and "have known".

Yes, Americans tend to use the simple past instead of the perfect form:

I always knew I could trust you.

versus

I have always known I could trust you.

